# difference between passing self or cls to __new__

Tags: python, singleton

I created Singleton class using below code (passing self as argument to **new**)

```
>>> class Singleton(object):
...     IsSingleton = None
...     def __new__(self):
...             if self.IsSingleton == None:
...                     print "Singleton IF"
...                     self.IsSingleton = super(Singleton, self).__new__(self)
...             print "ELSE"
...             return self.IsSingleton
```

and also created same using cls as argument to **new**

```
    >>> class Singleton(object):
    ...     IsSingleton = None
    ...     def __new__(cls):
    ...             if cls.IsSingleton == None:
    ...                     print "Singleton IF"
    ...                     cls.IsSingleton = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
    ...             print "ELSE"
    ...             return cls.IsSingleton
```

My question is if **new** is static method, how passing self to static method doesn't error out? What is difference between passing self or cls to **new**. As long as I have read, cls is passed to **new** not self. Is above same behaviour in two different set of code???

Comment: Calling the parameter `cls` or `self` is just convention. You can call it `x` or anything you want. But it _is_ a class, so `cls` is the appropriate name for it.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the parameter `cls` or `self` is just convention. You can call it `x` or anything you want. That won't alter the behaviour. But it *is* a class, so `cls` is the appropriate name for it.